# Table row count in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

In my page, for first time I will show only 10 records out of 36, if viewer click next button it shows next 10 records out of 36.

My problem is table row count on table footer

I don't know how to count table row on changing (meaning when we click next button it should say "showing 10 to 20 of 36 records".

**My output:**

[image]

**Expected outputs**:

[image]

after clicking **next button**: 
[image]

Sample code:

```
<tfoot>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${empty model}">
            <tr>
                <td align="left" colspan="11" style="color: orange; font-size: 12pt;">No records
                    found!</td>
            </tr>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" colspan="11" style="color: orange; font-size: 10pt;">Showing 1 to
                    ${stlRec} of ${ttlRec} entries
            </tr>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</tfoot>
```

Comment: you are generating this html using javascript isnt it ??

Comment: yes i m using javascript

Comment: please show us what u had done yet ??

Answer (score 3):

You can use [datatables](http://datatables.net), It will satisfy all your queries and has much more extras.

Or using jquery,

```
var row = $('#myTable tr').length;
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is very simple but you have to do some work.

1. fix the  height equal to your 10 records height.
2. Now append your all 36 records in that  and make "overflow:hidden" this will lock your  from showing more than 10 records.
3. now provide one button to see the more records, when user clicks on it make that  scrollTop(100) , this will move 100 px down and if you want to move up just give -100 but in place of 100 provide height of

i am 100% sure that this trick will solve your problem, because 3 days earlier i had done the same thing ha ha ....so enjoy, thanks. :)